# Proof of the formula for the atomic polarizability of a simple linear molecule

Tags: electrostatics, polarization, dipole-moment

For an atom Griffiths says

> $$
> \mathbf{p}=\alpha \mathbf{E}
> $$
> The constant of proportionality $\alpha$ is called atomic polarizability. And $\mathbf{E}$ is the external applied field

Then he goes on to give an equation of polarisation for a linear molecule like $\require{mhchem}\ce{CO2}$ as

> When the field is at some angle to the axis(of the molecule), you must resolve it into parallel and perpendicular components, and multiply each by the pertinent polarizability:
> $\mathbf{p}=\alpha_{\perp} \mathbb{E}_{\perp}+\alpha_{\|} \mathbb{E}_{\|}$.

What's the proof that the second equation follows from the first?

Comment: What to you need to proof? It is simply a decomposition of vector into the component along the axis and perpendicular to it?

Comment: What's the proof that polarisation obeys superposition?

Comment: polarisation is a dipole moment of unit volume, and the dipole moment obeys superposition, as well as $\mathbf E$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule when two vectors are related by an equation:

$$ \mathbf u = a \mathbf v $$

the object $a$ is a second rank tensor. This is commonly written as a matrix so the equation is actually:

$$  \begin{pmatrix} u_x  \\ u_y \\ u_z \end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix} a_{xx} & a_{xy} & a_{xz}  \\ a_{yx} & a_{yy} & a_{yz} \\ a_{zx} & a_{zy} & a_{zz} \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix} v_x  \\ v_y \\ v_z \end{pmatrix}  $$

Note that this means the two vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ may not point in the same direction e.g. the induced dipole may not be parallel to the applied field.

To simplify calculations it is often possible to choose axes in which the matrix is diagonal. These are the principal axes. In this case the equation simplifies to:

$$  \begin{pmatrix} u_x  \\ u_y \\ u_z \end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix} a_{xx} & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & a_{yy} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a_{zz} \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix} v_x  \\ v_y \\ v_z \end{pmatrix}  $$

And indeed if the system has cylindrical symmetry it will probably simplify further to:

$$  \begin{pmatrix} u_x  \\ u_y \\ u_z \end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix} a_{||} & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & a_{\perp} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a_{\perp} \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix} v_x  \\ v_y \\ v_z \end{pmatrix}  $$

where we are taking the $x$ direction to be along the axis of symmetry. Finally in many cases the system is isotropic and it simplifies still further to:

$$  \begin{pmatrix} u_x  \\ u_y \\ u_z \end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix} v_x  \\ v_y \\ v_z \end{pmatrix}  $$

or just:

$$ \mathbf u = a \mathbf v $$

where now $a$ is just a scalar. So when you ask:

> What's the proof that the second equation follows from the first?

you have this the wrong way round. The first equation follows from the second in the special case of an isotropic system. The second equation then follows from the more general tensor equation in the limit of cylindrical symmetry.

Comment: Thank you Mr John Rennie.

Comment: @John Rennie Should first we should prove that the induced dipole moment and electric field are related by matrix multiplication and then define this matrix as the polarizability?

Answer (score 1):

The second equation is more general: it reduces to the first one only if $\alpha_\perp = \alpha_\parallel = \alpha$. Even more generally the polarizability should be a tensor with 9 components:
$$
\mathbf{p} = \hat{\alpha}\mathbf{E}.
$$

One could generalize even further, by allowing for the polarizability to be non-local in time and space. And even in this case it would be not the most general answer, but only the linear response approximation.

Comment: Thank you, so is it that Griffiths simply quotes the result without proof?

Comment: It is actually a definition of polarizability, so there is no need to prove it. But if $\alpha$ is a constant (rather than a tensor) it applies only to some cases (clearly not to $CO_2$). You need to keep in mind that Griffiths is an introductory textbook, and, from what I heard, somewhat sloppy.

Comment: Thank you for your help.